# how can i simultaneously create a table (with javascript insertRow()) and populate it (via php) with data from the previous page

Tags: php, javascript, paypal, shopping-cart

I am creating a custom shopping cart, and need to send data from the product page to the cart page. The product form is for clothes, and has a table with several columns for sizes, and several rows for colors, and the buyer can enter the 'quantity' in the body of the table for each size/color. it will be a lot of input, and I would like to pass all of the information to a shopping cart on the next page, and have javascript create table rows/cells to contain all of the data. I will eventually use paypal to enter the whole shopping cart as one item.
Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: Your question is way too broad. But start by reading up about [AJAX](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd use PHP for this matter. Passing variables like you want to is way easier in PHP than say HTML or JS.

Recently I learned that using PHP `$_SESSION` variables for these issues but hell, you're not gonna pass -too- many variables (unless you're expecting multi-millionare customers) so why not give it a try with `$_SESSION` variables? They're very easy to use and cause little confusion within small systems.

Comment: Thanks guys, you answered my question....I guess some other people are so smart they just cant answer some questions!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against attempting to pass HTML content (your table data) from one page to the next via JavaScript.

I would "save" the changes on page (A) that the user selected... and then re-fetch the data from the database on page (B).

I think trying to do it all in JavaScript will become awkward and potentially open up security issues (e.g. a malicious user could tamper with/fake the data).

You'll also find that if you do use JavaScript instead of persisting this to your backend layer that you'll need to pass around this content on every page navigation without losing any of it which will become a major headache.  You're much better off saving it between pages so that nothing gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your requirement.

When you are in the product page, you can save the user actions in the database or in a temporary session using ajax. And then the user navigates to the cart page, again you can use ajax to get the values and then modify them to show them into a table.